# Sql date filter not working properly sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Date filter for date format 'ssss' in 'yyyy-mm-ddThh mm ss.sssz' is not working as expected.

[image]

I'm using queries:

```
select createdon from tableName where createdon<='2023-11-20T13:19:59.044'

select createdon from tableName where createdon<='2023-11-20T13:19:59.045'

select createdon from tableName where createdon<='2023-11-20T13:19:59.046'

select createdon from tableName where createdon<='2023-11-20T13:19:59.047'

select createdon from tableName where createdon<='2023-11-20T13:19:59.048'
```

second and third query should not return any result as date in the table is more than the filtered date.

Comment: Datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds, as explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#rounding-of-datetime-fractional-second-precision). What is the `createdon` column data type?

Comment: Just remove the 'T' from inside the filter date and you should be good to go. [Here si the correct format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes)

Comment: Plase provide the table structure and sample data on https://sqlize.online

Comment: @MatteoVioletto that's bad advice, the `T` makes the literal unambiguous. In T-SQL, a value like `'2023-11-20 13:19:59.048'` is ambiguous with the older date and time data types (`(small)datetime`). For someone like myself, `'2023-11-20T13:19:59.048'` would result in a conversion error, as there aren't 20 months in the year and SQL Server "thinks" that the date is in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`.

Comment: use datetime2 if you want avoid this kind of rounding issues

Comment: I found the solution. I'm using Datetime2. Thanks @Thom A